# Network doesn't works after hibernate/suspend system

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, suspend, hibernate

I have a Fedora 32 system and it works fine but when I suspend/hibernate the system  when it back to online the network is unreachable.

```
$ ip a show enp3s0
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:62:66:27:58:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.35/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have tried multiples forms to activate it but it's without success.

I have try :

```
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
$ ip a show enp3s0
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:62:66:27:58:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.35/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ 

$ sudo ifdown enp3s0 && sudo ifup enp3s0
Error: «/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp3s0» no es una conexión activa.
Error: no se proporcionó una conexión activa.
$ 

$ sudo nmcli networking off && sudo nmcli networking on
$ ip a show enp3s0
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:62:66:27:58:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ sudo ifdown enp3s0 && sudo ifup enp3s0
Error: «/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp3s0» no es una conexión activa.
Error: no se proporcionó una conexión activa.

$ 
$ sudo nmcli con down enp3s0 && sudo nmcli con up enp3s0
Error: «enp3s0» no es una conexión activa.
Error: no se proporcionó una conexión activa.

$ sudo nmtui (with gui)
```

All this form to activate fails but When I restart the system the network is working properly again.

Regards

***Update 1:***

**Before suspend the system (Work fine):**

```
$ nmcli device show enp3s0 
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0 
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet 
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:62:66:27:58:6F 
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500 
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (conectado) 
GENERAL.CONNECTION:     nmcli device show enp3s0 
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0 
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet 
GENERAL.HWADDR:                      enp3s0 
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3 
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               activado 
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.35/24 
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1 
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100 
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100 
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.222 
IP4.DNS[2]:                             1.1.1.1 
IP4.DNS[3]:                             8.8.8.8 
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

-- Pring to router
$ ping 192.168.1.1 
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data. 
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.394 ms 
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.293 ms

$ ip -br -c link show 
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP>  
enp3s0           UP             08:62:66:27:58:6f <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>  
virbr0           DOWN           52:54:00:c2:1b:e5 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>  
virbr0-nic       DOWN           52:54:00:c2:1b:e5 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  
[soyyo@aqua Scripts]$ ip -br -c addr show 
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8  
enp3s0           UP             192.168.1.35/24  
virbr0           DOWN           192.168.122.1/24  
virbr0-nic       DOWN
```

**After resume the system :**

```
$ nmcli device show enp3s0                                          
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0 
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet 
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:62:66:27:58:6F 
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500 
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (no disponible) 
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     -- 
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       -- 
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               desactivado 

$ sudo nmcli connection up abbecaa6-6237-333e-9eaf-c4f994c350cf    
Conexión activada con éxito (ruta activa D-Bus: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4) 

$ nmcli device show enp3s0                                         
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0 
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet 
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:62:66:27:58:6F 
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500 
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (conectado) 
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     enp3s0 
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4 
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               desactivado 
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.35/24 
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1 
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100 
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 20100 
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.222 
IP4.DNS[2]:                             1.1.1.1 
IP4.DNS[3]:                             8.8.8.8 

$ ping 192.168.1.1 
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data. 
From 192.168.1.35 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable 
From 192.168.1.35 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable 
From 192.168.1.35 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable 
From 192.168.1.35 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable 

$ ip -br -c link show 
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP>  
enp3s0           DOWN           08:62:66:27:58:6f <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>  
virbr0           DOWN           52:54:00:c2:1b:e5 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>  
virbr0-nic       DOWN           52:54:00:c2:1b:e5 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  
[soyyo@aqua Scripts]$ ip -br -c addr show 
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8  
enp3s0           DOWN           192.168.1.35/24  
virbr0           DOWN           192.168.122.1/24  
virbr0-nic       DOWN        

-- I try to up the device 
$ sudo ip link set enp3s0 up 

$ ip -br -c link show            
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP>  
enp3s0           DOWN           08:62:66:27:58:6f <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>  
virbr0           DOWN           52:54:00:c2:1b:e5 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>  
virbr0-nic       DOWN           52:54:00:c2:1b:e5 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST>
```

**Update 2:**

These are the ocurrences of systemd-rfkill.

**After normal boot:**

```
Tue 2021-01-26 20:36:23 CET aqua systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Succeeded.
-- The unit systemd-rfkill.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Tue 2021-01-26 20:36:23 CET aqua audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Tue 2021-01-26 20:36:18 CET aqua kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1611689778.178:91): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Tue 2021-01-26 20:36:18 CET aqua audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

**After back from resume:**

```
Tue 2021-01-26 20:41:07 CET aqua audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Tue 2021-01-26 20:41:07 CET aqua systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Succeeded.
-- The unit systemd-rfkill.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
-- Subject: A start job for unit systemd-rfkill.service has finished successfully
-- A start job for unit systemd-rfkill.service has finished successfully.
-- Subject: A start job for unit systemd-rfkill.service has begun execution
-- A start job for unit systemd-rfkill.service has begun execution.
Tue 2021-01-26 20:41:02 CET aqua audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

**Update 3.**

-- Before Suspend

```
$ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager 

● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager 
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-01-29 19:51:56 CET; 35min ago 
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8) 
   Main PID: 1204 (NetworkManager) 
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 38399) 
     Memory: 11.1M 
        CPU: 262ms 
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service 
             └─1204 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon 
 
ene 29 19:52:05 aqua NetworkManager[1204]: <info>  [1611946325.1522] device (enp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed') 
ene 29 19:52:05 aqua NetworkManager[1204]: <info>  [1611946325.1532] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed') 
ene 29 19:52:05 aqua NetworkManager[1204]: <info>  [1611946325.1544] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed') 
ene 29 19:52:05 aqua NetworkManager[1204]: <info>  [1611946325.1545] device (enp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed') 
ene 29 19:52:05 aqua NetworkManager[1204]: <info>  [1611946325.1548] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL 
ene 29 19:52:05 aqua NetworkManager[1204]: <info>  [1611946325.1557] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE 
ene 29 19:52:05 aqua NetworkManager[1204]: <info>  [1611946325.1558] policy: set 'enp3s0' (enp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS 
ene 29 19:52:05 aqua NetworkManager[1204]: <info>  [1611946325.1581] device (enp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated. 
ene 29 19:52:08 aqua NetworkManager[1204]: <info>  [1611946328.4583] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL 
ene 29 19:53:43 aqua NetworkManager[1204]: <info>  [1611946423.9003] agent-manager: agent[420a8f889bafe72e,:1.78/org.kde.plasma.networkmanagement/1001]: agent registered
```

-- After Suspend

```
$ sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager && sudo systemctl start NetworkManager 
$ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager 
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager 
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-01-29 20:28:55 CET; 9s ago 
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8) 
   Main PID: 112720 (NetworkManager) 
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 38399) 
     Memory: 3.3M 
        CPU: 85ms 
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service 
             └─112720 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon 
 
ene 29 20:28:55 aqua NetworkManager[112720]: <info>  [1611948535.8664] device (58:D9:C3:5D:4A:81): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external') 
ene 29 20:28:55 aqua NetworkManager[112720]: <info>  [1611948535.8672] agent-manager: agent[0b56fd872b56034c,:1.78/org.kde.plasma.networkmanagement/1001]: agent registered 
ene 29 20:28:55 aqua NetworkManager[112720]: <info>  [1611948535.8673] device (58:D9:C3:5D:4A:81): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed') 
ene 29 20:28:55 aqua NetworkManager[112720]: <info>  [1611948535.8754] device (virbr0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'assume') 
ene 29 20:28:55 aqua NetworkManager[112720]: <info>  [1611948535.8781] device (virbr0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'assume') 
ene 29 20:28:55 aqua NetworkManager[112720]: <info>  [1611948535.8821] device (virbr0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'assume') 
ene 29 20:28:55 aqua NetworkManager[112720]: <info>  [1611948535.8825] device (virbr0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'assume') 
ene 29 20:28:55 aqua NetworkManager[112720]: <info>  [1611948535.8828] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL 
ene 29 20:28:55 aqua NetworkManager[112720]: <info>  [1611948535.8833] device (virbr0): Activation: successful, device activated. 
ene 29 20:29:01 aqua NetworkManager[112720]: <info>  [1611948541.8354] manager: startup complete 

$ ping 192.168.1.1 
ping: connect: La red es inaccesible
```

**Update 4**

```
]$ ping 192.168.1.1 
ping: connect: La red es inaccesible 

$ sudo dhclient enp3s0 
dhclient(6463) is already running - exiting.  
 
This version of ISC DHCP is based on the release available 
on ftp.isc.org. Features have been added and other changes 
have been made to the base software release in order to make 
it work better with this distribution. 
 
Please report issues with this software via:  
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/ 
 
exiting. 

$ ping 192.168.1.1     
ping: connect: La red es inaccesible
```

** Update 5 **

```
$ ping 192.168.1.1 
ping: connect: La red es inaccesible 

$ ethtool -i enp3s0  
driver: r8169 
version: 5.10.8-100.fc32.x86_64 
firmware-version: rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 
expansion-rom-version:  
bus-info: 0000:03:00.0 
supports-statistics: yes 
supports-test: no 
supports-eeprom-access: no 
supports-register-dump: yes 
supports-priv-flags: no 

$ sudo modprobe -vr r8169 && sudo modprobe -v r8169  
rmmod r8169 
insmod /lib/modules/5.10.8-100.fc32.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8169.ko.xz  

$ ping 192.168.1.1                                   
ping: connect: La red es inaccesible
```

Comment: Have you check for system messages before/after suspend/hibernate?  Perhaps something isn't being restarted/reinitialized.

Comment: I don't find any problem in message file.

Comment: Any mention of `systemd-rfkill` in the system messages?

Comment: Yes, I answer you in the update 2.

Comment: What happens with `sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager && sudo systemctl start NetworkManager`?

Comment: Nothing. The network is inaccesible..

Comment: After the `... stop... && ... start... `, what does `sudo systemctl status NetworkManager` show?

Comment: I have added an Update 3 with the output of the status command.

Comment: What happens after `sudo dhclient enp3s0`?

Comment: After suspend is already up (update 4)

Comment: Interesting puzzle!  What's the output of `ethtool -i enp3s0`?  I wonder if removing and then reloading the kernel module might allow the carrier to become active.  I.e., after getting the driver from the output of `ethtool`, try `sudo modprobe -vr YourModuleName  && sudo modprobe -v YourModuleName`.

Comment: I have probed before and after suspend and in both case the network goes down. Details in update 5.

Comment: After reloading the kernel module, the device/network/connection will need to be reactivated, by perhaps NetworkManager.  If you upgrade to the latest kernel version, is there any difference?

Comment: Hi, I have solved the problem but I dón't understand which was the problem. I have erased the network file configuration and recreate it again with network gui tool. Now I can suspend/hibernate the pc and boot with network. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting the network file configuration and recreate it again with network gui tool.

Regards